# Why is an empty apex:attribute neither null nor blank but still an empty string?

Tags: visualforce-component, string, null, isblank, empty

Consider this simple component:

```
<apex:component access="public" layout="none">
    <apex:attribute name="myString" type="String" />

    {!ISNULL(myString)} {!ISBLANK(myString)} {!myString == ''}
</apex:component>
```

Just using the component yields the following values:

```
<c:MyComponent />
```

> true true true

And it gets even weirder if you use it without an actual value:

```
<c:MyComponent myString="" />
```

> false false true

Why? Why on earth is a "empty" attribute not blank or null but an omitted attribute is - plus both equal an empty string! Afaicr ISNULL is just an alias for ISBLANK - is this correct? But aside from that - why on earth does a blank string not equal an empty string? Why does it differ?

I hope someone can explain this weird behavior.

Also: Can I differentiate between an empty attribute and an omitted attribute?

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with `component` or `attribute`. Your real question is *why is an empty string not blank*?

Comment: That is not my question because `String.isBlank('')` is always true. Plus: In my example it seems to be an empty string in both cases - but it is only blank in one case.

Comment: But this isn't `Apex`, it's `Visualforce`.

Comment: True. Forget about the Apex-part. In this Visualforce-example I still have an empty string in both cases but only in one case it's also blank.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what markup you're using in the first and second example. You've only shown one version.

Comment: The markup is the same - just the caller is different. I've clarified the example.